# Is it possible to earn $200 a month by freelancing?

Tags: freelance-websites, marketing

I've been trying to earn just $200 a month for five years now but I failed!

1. I tried tons of PTC and surveys websites and I found out that they are scam or they pay too low. They don't worth it. I spend a lot of time and effort testing those websites.
2. I tried to sell some images and pictures on some websites (I don't recall their names because that was in the past) and no one bought them.
3. I've created many blogs and I failed to gain traffic. Finally, I build a blog that is not in English. It has more than 10,000 views per month. But I earn about as low as $3 a month!!
4. I teach my native language on youtube. My channel has more than 10,000 views per months too and 2K subscribers. I earn about $12 a month. That's very low too.
5. Currently, I work as a transcriber. This gives me $30 a month at most. Maybe that's because they don't have a large number of customers.
6. I've just graduated this year. I really need to get $200 a month because they are enough for my living. If I managed to do it, I don't have to get a real work. I can work online. So, I applied to one of the websites that can make me earn $10 per a tested website. I applied twice but I failed.
7. I created accounts on Fiverr and Freelancer but no one buys my gigs or hires me.

Could you tell me a way to get $200 a month, Please? I need a trusted (legit) website that gives me a job. I prefer not to search for customers or get traffic. I need direct tasks or jobs like what I do as a transcriber. The website gives me files to transcribe, Then I get paid.

I've many skills. I can type very fast. I'm an expert in photoshop, MS word, power point, excel. I've two languages (English and Arabic) so I can work as a translator.

Thank you so much,

Comment: Develop a niche expertise, become the best at it and sell your services to large enterprises. Don't enter in those scams ran by some nobodies, this won't work. Study hard and put a lot of efforts in a "job" that you can do remotely. You can easily make $200 before eating your breakfast if you work hard enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propose your translation services (only to your mother tongue) for 10$ an hour. You should be able to find 20 hours of work per month.

Possibly typing, but I would expect the fees to be lower, as this takes no real skills.

Be sure to refine your profile and show example translations. You can propose free trials, but of a limited extent !

Comment: translation services?what is that?

Answer (score 2):

$200 freelancing a month is actually very low. Many freelancers make more than that from their works in just a day.

Unfortunately, there is no magic bullet for you to make money. It's unusual for new graduates to survive in the online freelancing market unless you have something special to offer for. You can't compete with other experienced freelancers around the world.

You will need to be good in something, I mean problem-domain experts and show it somewhere. Don't bother those websites again, they won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to develop your your skills. The ones you listed, every kid fresh out of school can do that - no need to find a stranger of the internet, just ask in the neighbourhood.

Also, what you listed above that you tried in the past I would not count as freelancing. What I understand as freelancing is: Being so proficient/expert in one specific field of work and being able to sell that to different parties so you are better off than someone doing similar things in a fixed employment situation.

Most successful freelancers did get where they are, by first learning the trade and building their network in a normal job and only took up freelancing when they saw an opportunity to survive economically at a later stage.

Try finding a field you are passionate about, get really good in that field. Then see if freelancing is an option for your.

Answer (score 1):

I started freelancing about 6 years ago. One thing I have noticed in the last few years is that local connections really matter. (It might just be for me.)

Getting people to talk about your work really helps when you work as a freelancer, they might just talk about you with a potential client. You can also start off with websites like Upwork, try creating a solid profile there (it matters).

Lastly, although freelancing is a blast, try working with a company or agency. Learn the ropes of the business, build connections. I recently started with an agency and I have got to say.. There is a lot I did not know about running a freelance business and my skills until I started working with an agency.